# Find radical expressions for all three roots of $t^3-15t-4=0$.

Tags: polynomials, roots, radicals

I understand that I can use the trigonometric identity $4\cos^3(\theta)-3\cos(\theta)-\cos(3\theta)=0 \tag{2}$ to find the three real roots, and Cardano's formula gives the radical expression for t=4; but how exactly do I find the radical expressions for the other two real roots? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $t^3-15t-4 = (t-4)(t^2 +4t+1)  $

Comment: @WillJagy Brilliant. Thank you so much!

Comment: Cardano formula gives all three roots.

Comment: @markvs how so?

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35CUGKB4DrQ

Comment: @markvs Interesting...That is indeed a bit different from Ian Stewart's book.

Comment: Fortunately, I never needed to read Stewart's book. If the formula gives only one  root of $3$, then which one? Notice that there are $3$ cube roots from every complex number except $0$.

Comment: @markvs Oh in Stewart's the one root then leads to 9 solutions; but the difference, I believe, is that if they are not all complex's, then there could be duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t=4$ is a solution, then it will be in this form

$t^3-15t-4=(t-4)(t^2+bt+1)$

By putting a suitable number for $t$

For example $t=1$

$-18=(-3)(2+b)$

$b=4$

$t^3-15t-4=(t-4)(t^2+4t+1)$

That radical part can be find in different ways: Horner's method, Polynomial division,...